# asp .net core 3 localization issue causing pages to break

Tags: c#, localization, .net-core-3.0

We having an issue with localization where certain pages are not loading. I understand this was a feature added in core 3. With our project we do not need to use this feature. We do need to use only one localization setting to make sure date format is displaying correctly and when data is stored matches the time of the configured location. Is there a way to disable this feature ?

Comment: No, localization always existed in ASP.NET, going back to 2002. Which means, it's impossible to guess what the problem is or what's wrong. You don't provide any information.

Comment: In *all* stacks going back to 2002, by default the web site tries to detect the end user's locale through the preferred language headers. I suspect your end users use a different locale from the one you want. Or the *developers* use a different locale, eg English, and so see a different format than the one the end users will see. You can override this in many places, but consider whether you *want* to. In public facing web sites you can expect users from different locales.

Comment: If you *don't* want locale detection, you can specify a specific culture at the project, page or request level, binding expressions and all parsing and formatting methods. What you decide to do depends on the business requirements. Using a fixed culture for the entire project is probably appropriate for intranet applications. Unless you live in Belgium. If you want to have different pages for different languages, you should specify the culture at the page level.

Comment: Finally, on forums, it's customary for users to store their preferred culture in their profile. The application can read that on each request and set the current thread's culture to that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the reply. Our requirement would be to set each request to a certain locale setting